# Is this a bad way to construct an object inside of an object?

Tags: javascript

I am using this code to make VN.CH.Mister1 using the VN.CH.Make() function inside the VN.CH object but feel like it is weird and inefficient and have been unable to find a more effective way of doing it, preferably all inside the object, while looking online.

```
let VN = {
    CH: {
        Make: function(name) {
            this.Name = name;
            this.Exists = 1;
        }
    }
};

VN.CH.Mister1 = new VN.CH.Make('Mister1');
```

If anyone could help explain a more effective way of doing this, or a way to do it all inside of the VN.CH object or point out any misunderstandings I might have about Javascript in general from what you see here I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Do you need the `Make` constructor for any reason?

Comment: Naming conventions are very bad in your code. Variable, function and key names should start with lower case

Comment: @JuBa: Normally, variable names start with a lower-case letter, as do property names. So `VN` => `vn`, `CH` => `ch`, `Name` => `name`, `Exists` => `exists`. Initially-capped names are for constructor functions, so `Make` is fine.

Comment: I am going to put functions in there that I want the objects I make using it to have without having to put them in each created object individually.

Comment: @JuBa - Um...is that a "yes, I need the `Make` constructor"? :-) If so, what you have is fine (other than naming). What issue do you have with it?

Comment: @TJ - I was wondering if the process I was using to do this was poorly coded and the answers have helped.

Answer (score 1):

If you need the `Make` constructor and it has to be on `vn.ch`, what you have is fine other than using non-standard naming. Obviously you can do what you like in your own code, and there is sometimes call to make an exception, but overwhelmingly the naming standards in JavaScript are that variables and properties start with a lower-case letter, so:

```
let vn = {
    ch: {
        Make: function(name) {
            this.name = name;
            this.exists = 1;
        }
    }
};

vn.ch.mister1 = new vn.ch.Make('Mister1');
```

If you don't need the `Make` constructor, you can do it more simply:

```
let vn = {
    ch: {
        mister1: {
            name: "Mister1",
            exists: 1
        }
    }
};
```

If the `Make` constructor doesn't have to be on `vn.ch`, then:

```
function Make(name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.exists = 1;
}

let vn = {
    ch: {
        mister1: new Make("Mister1")
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I would separate the concerns of object creation and the place where the objects are stored. Here is an example of how you could achieve this (among many other ways):

```js
let peopleObj = {}  // Here is where you objects life

function make (name) {   // Here is where you create them
  this.name = name;
  this.exists = 1;
}

peopleObj.Mister1 = new make('Mister1');
peopleObj.Mister2 = new make('Mister2');

console.log(peopleObj);
```

Comment: I see now how the constructor doesn't have to be in the object where I want the result to be, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you want `CH` to manage some kind of collection of `Person` objects (i.e. the kind of object that `VN.CH.Make` creates). So, instead of writing

VN.CH.Mister1 = new VN.CH.Make('Mister1');

you could put a constructor function `Make` on `VN.CH` and write a function `VN.CH.make` which adds new instances.

**CODE:**

```js
const VN = {
  CH: {
    Make: function Make(name) {
      this.name = name;
      this.exists = 1;
    },
    make(name) {
      this[name] = new this.Make(name);
    }
  }
};
    
VN.CH.make('Mister1');

console.log(VN.CH.Mister1);
```

---

Ultimately however, I think it's clearer if you abstract your code by creating two classes with separate concerns:

- `PersonRegistry` which creates `Person` instances and manages them; and,
- `Person` which represents a person with a `name` and `exists` property

and then just make `VN.CH` point to an instance of `PersonRegistry`:

**CODE:**

```js
class Person {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.exists = 1;
  }
}

class PersonRegistry {
  constructor() {
    this.instances = {};
  }
  
  make(name) {
    this.instances[name] = new Person(name);
  }
  
  get(name) {
    return this.instances[name] || null;
  }
}

const VN = {
    CH: new PersonRegistry()
};

VN.CH.make('Lady1');
VN.CH.make('Mister1');
VN.CH.make('LadyA');
VN.CH.make('MisterA');

console.log(VN.CH.get('Lady1'));
console.log(VN.CH.get('Mister1'));
console.log(VN.CH.get('LadyA'));
console.log(VN.CH.get('MisterA'));
```

Note that you actually don't need the class declarations (you could just as well work with object literals); but, working with classes expresses your intentions more clearly imo and you can add subclasses later if needed.